# Value of input field is not position correctly after applying css animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

EDIT - I'm using safari on Mac and iPad to test this

I have the following code which consists of a styled input field.

The input field jumps onto the screen with a CSS animation effect. Ok, this works great.

[image]

2. But when I try to apply another animation effect using javascript (shake - to mimic an error in the input), the value attribute moves to the bottom of the input field leaving very little padding between the text and the bottom border. I am not sure why this happens.

[image]

The effect itself works fine, but the positioning is all incorrect. Please see and run the code snippet. Any help will be most appreciated

The JS I use to add the shake effect is:

```
$('#EmailInput').removeClass('animated-second bounceInUp').addClass('animated shake').addClass('error-msg');
```

```css
input[type="email"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
input[type="email"] {
  height: 42px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
  line-height: normal;
}
#EmailInput,
#EmailInput:focus {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.15em;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 3em;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
/*For the bounce*/

.animated-third {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated-second {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.animated-first {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(2000px);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.bounceInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  animation-name: bounceInUp;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br>
<div style="margin: 20px auto; width: 70%">
  <input class="animated-third bounceInUp" name="email" type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" id="EmailInput" value="haha@hah.com">
</div>
```

Comment: works fine in FF46

Comment: @dippas Sorry, I forgot to mention this is on Safari on MacOS and iPad